# C# DLL - Returning data using DataTable

Tags: c#, dll, datatable, return

I'm trying to create some code for a dll file to return data called from a SQL Database using a DataTable.

My present issue is, with the code below, I'm getting the error message "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields and methods."

```
public DataTable getData(string cmdText)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LIVE"].ConnectionString))
            {
                da.SelectCommand = con.CreateCommand();
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                da.SelectCommand.CommandText = cmdText;
                da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ec)
                {

                }
                finally
                {

                    con.Close();
                }

            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Anyone have any suggestions or can help?

Many thanks,

G

Comment: "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields and methods." Methods belong inside types (either a class or a struct). Your method is not contained in a type, based on the error message.

Comment: Can you show us your full file? with the namespace?

Comment: it looks like you're fairly new to C# and ADO.NET, but: `DataTable` is *not* a good technology to be using in (current year). If you can *at all* avoid that, frankly: I would. Virtually anything would be preferable! "Dapper" would be a good choice if you want to work with command text and connections, but don't want `DataTable`

Comment: Is that code you posted inside a class? can you post more of that file (the whole namespace)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one class inside your namespace, for example this would fix your error:

```
namespace MyDll
{
    public static class Data
    {

        public static DataTable Get(string cmdText)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LIVE"].ConnectionString))
            {
                da.SelectCommand = con.CreateCommand();
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                da.SelectCommand.CommandText = cmdText;
                da.SelectCommand.Connection = con;
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ec)
                {

                }
                finally
                {

                    con.Close();
                }

            }
            return dt;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, but when I try this I get the error message against the 'Cannot declare instance members in a static class' against the Public static class Get.

Comment: Sorry I had one mistake, just add also static to the method.